# Geoplugin returns false - PHP

Tags: php, geolocation

I'm trying to understand the issues with geoplugin, Using the following code I get an inconsistent result.

Sometimes I get the geo location, and sometimes file_get_contents returns false.

The geoplugin url is accessible through the browser, so the page exists.

PHPinfo info shows : **allow_url_fopen  On  On**
My main concern is the inconsistency, Why sometimes it works and sometimes it fails, Almost as if the geoplugin.net server blocks my server.

Using google's IP to repliace the problem:

```
$query = http_build_query(array('ip'=>"74.125.230.83"));
$url = "http://www.geoplugin.net/json.gp?" . $query;
var_dump($url);
var_dump(file_get_contents($url)); - returns false.
```

file_get_contents('http://www.google.com'); works fine, so it's not a function issue.
This is not consistent and can come and go without warning.

So my question : How can I even begin to debug this?
Has anyone ever encountered this problem before?

Comment: It works perfectly fine, I don't know what do you want to debug ?

Comment: The fact that on my server, on some occasions, it returns false instead of data